# How do I keep a div visible when the user goes to a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So, the user clicks something and then a div pops out from the left side.

Then I save via a cookie whether or not the div is "visible" or "hidden" in JavaScript.

```
$('#click').click(function()
{
    save_cookie('div', 'visible');

    $('.class').animate({'margin-right': '-20px'});

    return false;
});

if(get_cookie('div') != null)
{
    if(get_cookie('div') == 'visible')
    {
        $('.class').css({'margin-right': '-20px'});
    }
    else
    {
        $('.class').css({'margin-right': '0px'});
    }
}
```

So, if the user decides to go to a different page, I check whether or not I should display the div or not.

And the problem I'm having is that the div "blinks" for a second, when the user goes to a different page. And I know this is due to the fact that it takes a few seconds before the HTML, CSS and JavaScript is loaded.

But I was wondering if there is a better technique on how to do this? So it doesn't "blink."

BTW, I also tried to move the JavaScript to the `head` (from the bottom), but this also didn't change anything. :/

Comment: The only way I could think of to do this would be to load the whole page via AJAX, but this has a downside with regards to JS support, URLs etc. You could however minimise the time it takes to show by putting your `div` at the start of your `body` tag

Comment: Oh yeah, smart thinking. I had the div all the way on the bottom. Thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your javascript inside document.ready? It shouldn't be really, not if you want to avoid the flicker. I'd add it to the head just in it's own little script and use it to add a class to the html element. Then style the div to appear when that class is present.

Comment: Yah, I had it inside the document.ready. Lemme try it your way.

Comment: just make sure the script appears after the element it is targeting in the dom

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to apply `display:none` in css as default value for div and change it then accordingly from jQuery.

Comment: My default value is `marign-right:0px;`, should have the same effect, but it still has the "flicker" if the div needs to be visible when the page is loaded. :/

Comment: If you set `display:none` as default, javascript will show the `div` without make any flicker. It will just show it, if necessary, when checks `if` condition.

Comment: @Sotiris - I think the flicker @krysis is talking about is the div appearing when the javascript unhides it.

Answer (score 0):

You are close to the right code methodology - what you may want to change though is to start the page with the DIV visible, then animate it retracting. This hints to the user that there is something else that can appear (your div) and also makes it load properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an iFrame that is the size of the browser window for main navigation, and have the overlay work happen outside the iFrame.